# How to sketch $y = \frac1{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: graphing-functions

How to sketch $y = \frac1{\sqrt{x-1}}$

My way:(which does not work here)

I normally solve these problems by squaring and converting them to equations of 2 degree curves(such as parabola, hyperbola, etc.) which I can easily plot. But this seems to go 3 degree as $xy^2$ term is coming.

Please help me to solve this.

Note: Please don't say to use a graph plotter and see for myself since in the exam if this question comes I won't have the graph plotter with me.

Comment: Sketch the graph of $y=\sqrt x$. Shift it to the right $1$ unit (to get the graph of $y=\sqrt{x-1}$). Invert this graph to obtain the graph of your function.  (Transformation techniques are sometimes very handy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider some basic properties of the function, which you can work out either by inspection or by considering derivatives:

- It is only defined for $x \ge 1$;
- It has no roots, stationary points, inflection points, etc.;
- It is always decreasing and convex;
- It tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$;
- It tends to $\infty$ as $x \to 1^+$.

Just this information is enough for you to give a rough sketch of the function.

If you want to make it more accurate then you could consider some points which the function passes through, e.g. $(2,1)$ and $(5,2)$.

Comment: @CliveNewsteed How did you decide that this curve is always decreasing and convex ?

Comment: @user2369284: By looking at the sign of $y'$ and $y''$ (or just by inspection: there's nothing else it *could* do!).

Comment: @CliveNewsteed And how does the sign of $y^{'}$ and $y^{''}$ matter.

Comment: Because $y'$ tells you whether the function is increasing or decreasing (if $y'>0$ then the function is increasing and if $y'<0$ then it's decreasing), and $y''$ tells you whether the function is convex or concave (likewise).

Comment: @CliveNewsteed Can't we analyse the curve for $y = x^{-0.5}$ and then shift the origin to (1,0).

Comment: @user2369284: Yes, you can do that... but how was I meant to know that you knew how to sketch *that* function? The method I suggested would work even if you didn't know how to sketch that one.

Answer (score 1):

HINT : What is the domain of $x$? What happens if you make $x$ larger, larger, to infinity? What happens if you make $x$ closer to $1$ from the right side?

Comment: The domain is $(1,\infty)$

Comment: Yes. And how about the other two?

Comment: As x becomes larger, y becomes 0. and as x comes closer to 1, y becomes infinity.

Comment: Yes. Now you know how it looks like. Then, you should know y', y'' in order to know the exact form.

Comment: Can't we analyse the curve for $y=x^{−0.5}$ and then shift the origin to (1,0)

Comment: Good idea. But beforehand you need to know about $y=x^{-\frac 12}$, right? If you know it, then it's a good idea. By the way, if you experience many curves, you'll know the shape of the curve at once.